# How to solve the question related to geometry.

Tags: geometry

**The question is** :

If $AB$ and $CD$ be two chords of a circle meets at $E$ then show that $\frac {AE} {CE}  = \frac {DE} {BE}$.

I don't find any clue to solve it.Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can construct lines $AC$ and $DB$ to form two triangles, $\Delta ACE$ and $\Delta DBE$.  We know that $\lt AEC \cong \lt DEB$ because they are vertical angles.  We also know that $\lt CAE \cong \lt BDE$. We know this because these two angles are both inscribed angles and they intercept the same arc. Using this, we can say that $\Delta ACE \sim \Delta BDE$ through Angle Angle Similarity. Therefore, corresponding sides are in proportion, so we can say that $\frac {AE}{CE}=\frac {DE}{BE}$. You might also see $AE \cdot BE=CE \cdot DE$ which is the same as the previous proportion, just simplified.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that  $\triangle CAE$ and  $\triangle BDE$ are similar. Hence $\dfrac{AE}{DE} = \dfrac{CE}{BE}$

$  \angle AEC  = \angle DEB \qquad \text{ (opposite angles)} \\ \angle CAE = \angle BDC $

Comment: Arya how can I prove that the angles which you mention are equal?

Comment: Do you provide me the diagram?

Comment: Angle subtended by an arc at centre of circle id double the  angle subtended by same arc at circumference.By this property,angles in the same segment of a circle are equal.     http://gradestack.com/CBSE-Class-9th-Complete/Circles/Theorem-6-Angles-in-the/14904-2953-4031-study-wtw